# Bootstrap 4 full height template

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I have been trying for ages to make this work but have not been able to 
get it to where I need it. Due to using React the markup is slightly more complex than a standard bootstrap template:

```
<div id="root">
    <div class="app">
        <nav class="navbar">
            ...
        </nav>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    sidebar
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    main content
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to get the sidebar column and the main content column to fill the screen. The closest I have got is that they are 100% height but then that makes the page longer than it actually is.

Any ideas would be great. Thanks!

**Update:**
I have just done the same setup in a pure html file and it works, it looks to be something that is happening in webpack/react

**Update:**
A little more research and I have a further understanding of what is going on.

So, setting `height: 100%` on and element doesnt make any difference, `#root` is full height using `min-height: 100vh` which is greate but adding `height:100%` to anything beneath that does absolutely nothing

Comment: it might be caused by navbar you are adding(if it is not fixed). I suggest you to make it fixed. Then you can give your container fluid a top padding as high as navbar.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using React the problem might be that you use `class` instead of  `className`.

```
<div id="root">
    <div className="app">
        <nav className="navbar">
            ...
        </nav>
        <div className="container-fluid">
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-3">
                    sidebar
                </div>
                <div className="col">
                    main content
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks but i just put a simplified version in here as not everybody would know className. But in my actual code I do use className